# Getting Button and Anchor Tag on Same Line in li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a collapsible menu (using Bootstrap 3) that uses a unordered list with links (anchor tags) as the list items. I would like to be able to get a small "delete" button to appear on the same line as the anchor tag text, but it keeps wrapping. The intention is for the delete button to appear next to whatever the "active" link in the list is, which would be easy enough if I could get the layout/style correct. Here is a jsfiddle - look under "Header 2" to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/jpatchak/2dvxL5dv/6/

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and JQuery 2.1.3.

CSS:

```
ul.nav-list.my-tree
    {
        padding:0px 20px;
    }
    li.my-tree-item
    {
        padding:0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        line-height: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    li.my-divider
    {
        height: 2px;
        margin:9px 1px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:#e5e5e5;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    label.my-toggler.my-nav-header
    {

        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .my-nav-header
    {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 20px;
        color:#999;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
li a 
{
    overflow: hidden; 
    display: inline-block; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="well col-sm-4" style="height:1000px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="my-divider"></li>
        <li>
            <label class="my-nav-header my-toggler">Header 1</label>
            <ul class="nav nav-list tree my-tree">
                <li class="my-tree-item"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
                <li class="my-tree-item"><a href="#">Second Item With Really Long Text</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="my-divider"></li>
        <li>
            <label class="my-nav-header my-toggler">Header 2</label>
            <ul class="nav nav-list tree my-tree">
                <li class="my-tree-item"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
                <li class="my-tree-item"><a href="#">Second Item With Really Long Text</a><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></li><!--this is where I want the text (with ellipses) and the button on the same line...
            </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Some JQuery for the animation:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('ul.my-tree').css('display', 'none');
});

$('label.my-toggler').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children('ul.my-tree').toggle(300);

});
```

Comment: Is the automatic ellipsis a must have?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is. I will be putting the entire text in the "title" attribute  to provide a tool tip, but I need to truncate the long text with ellipses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following rule to your css that loads after the bootstrap one:

```
.nav>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(100% - 48px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dvxL5dv/7/

Answer (score 0):

May be you could change your css for this :

```
.btn-group-xs>.btn, .btn-xs {
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -33px;//or left:0; if you want it on the other side
    top: 0;
}
li.my-tree-item {
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    line-height: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your .btn class the following if you want it to the right of the anchor:

```
.btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: -33px;
    top: 0;
    /* the rest of your styles here */
}
```

Otherwise change the "right" to a left and adjust if you want it on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/2dvxL5dv/8/

```
li.my-tree-item a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    li.my-tree-item .btn {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Just added these codes.